# How to make an app close all older instances of itself

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app that launches by default when a certain device is plugged in. When in a different app/on the home screen and the device is plugged in, the app starts without any problems. However, when the app is open beforehand, it opens a second instance then both instances close when the device is plugged in.

The app also must absolutely close itself when the user returns to the home screen, which is what the following code is for:

```
public void onStop(){
    System.exit(2);        
}
```

When this code is removed, the app relaunches when the device is plugged in but does not restart properly, and is also missing the functionality that the app closes when not in the foreground (due to the nature of the device plugged in, closing when going to the home screen is necessary for the app - I understand it is not common practice).

It seems to me that the reason both instances close is because `System.exit(2)` executes after the second instance launches, which then closes both instances. Is there a way to make it so my app launches a new instance without this issue?

Comment: "when the app is open beforehand, it opens a second instance" -- no, it does not. It might open a second instance of an activity from your app. "which is what the following code is for" -- this is unlikely to do anything good for you or the user. "the app relaunches when the device is plugged in but does not restart properly" -- you might want to post a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] and a detailed description of what "does not restart properly" means. Perhaps we can help you address this in better ways.

Comment: "closing when going to the home screen is necessary for the app - I understand it is not common practice" -- correct. There are good reasons for this. "Is there a way to make it so my app launches a new instance without this issue?" -- not really.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your explanation. I was able to make a workaround using the singleTop launch mode (using a different approach that still works with the finicky external device). Unfortunately I cannot give enough code for a minimal reproducible example as this app is entirely built around external hardware, but I may come back later this week and try to make a hardware-independent example.

Comment: "I was able to make a workaround using the singleTop launch mode" -- that is substantially better than trying to terminate your process. I'm glad that you got this working!